# How do I set my code so it allows the values "X" and "O" in the buttons?

Tags: java, swing, methods, handler, tic-tac-toe

I'm doing a tic tac toe board game. I already have the board in the window, but I don't know how to use the handler method to set the values in the buttons so the players can really play. This is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TicTacToeGame implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {

   private NscWindow win;
   private JButton[][] button;
   private boolean turnX;
   private JLabel label;


   public TicTacToeGame () {
     win = new NscWindow(10,10, 235, 280);
     win.setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");

     javax.swing.JButton btn;
     button = new JButton[3][3];

     JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];

     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

          button[i][j] = new JButton();
          button[i][j].setSize(50, 50);
          button[i][j].setLocation(30 + i*55, 30+ j*55);
          win.add(button[i][j]);
          button[i][j].addActionListener(this);
          win.repaint();

     javax.swing.JLabel label;
     label = new JLabel("X's turn", JLabel.CENTER);
     label.setSize(160, 20);
     label.setLocation(30, 200);
     win.add(label);
     win.repaint();


         }
     }
   }
   //Abstract method
   public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

     javax.swing.JButton button;
     button = (javax.swing.JButton)e.getSource();
     button.setText("");

     //count++;

     // if(count %2 != 0) {
     //letter = "X";
     //}else{
     //letter = "O";

     //}


   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new TicTacToeGame();
   }
}
```

Comment: You're already calling `button.setText("")`, so presumably you understand what this method does -- so why not do the obvious -- call the method after setting letter's reference and then pass in the letter variable into this method? I'm somewhat boggled as to why you haven't tried this yet.

Comment: If I put "X" in  there, it will always put "X" in each button. I don't know if you understand my question. It suppose to be playable.

Comment: No, I didn't say to put the "X" in there, I said for you to but the letter variable in there **after** you've set it. Uncomment the code at the bottom of the handler's actionPerformed method, and then call `button.setText(letter)` below where you set the value of letter. Again, why won't this work? I don't think that you understand my suggestion. Better still, use a Model-View-Control structure so that you set the text of the buttons based on the state of your model. This is one way that you can assure that a button doesn't change if it's already set.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you for your suggestion. I'll try that and see how it goes.

Comment: And I do have [some experience with the Java Swing Tic Tac Toe problem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a522444%20tic%20tac%20toe). Please for instance check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23097448/522444) that creates an MVC Tic Tac Toe program.

Answer (score 2):

The simple quick-fix: as noted in my comments, simply call `setText(...)` on your selected button **after** setting letter's value. You would first check the text to be sure that it isn't empty, something like:

```
// code not tested.
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    // get the button pressed
    javax.swing.JButton button = (javax.swing.JButton)e.getSource();
    // get the button's text
    String text = button.getText();

    // if the text either holds spaces or is empty
    if (text.trim().isEmpty()) {
        count++;
        String letter = ""; // declare letter outside of the if/else block

        // find out whose turn, and assign appropriate String to letter
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            letter = "0";
        } else {
            letter = "X";
        }

        // use letter to set button's text
        button.setText(letter);
    }
}
```

The better over-all solution is to use an MVC like program structure such as can be found in [this solution to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097448/522444).

Comment: @user5183901: if you still need help, then consider telling and showing us more by editing your original post, leaving the original code unchanged, but adding new code and new details of your problem in an edit below the original code and explanation. Then re-flag me and I'll take a look at it.