# Alternate displayed image

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm doing a TicTacToe, and the idea is that in the first time I click one button it shows the image "X" , if i click other button it shows the image "O" ... and it continues, showing the images alternately. I was also trying that with one click at the button it shows one image, but if i click again at that button the image disappear.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class XOButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{
  ImageIcon X;
  ImageIcon O;
  byte value=0;
  byte k=0;

public XOButton(){
    try {
        X=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("X.png"));
        O=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("O.png"));
        addActionListener(this);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("The image is not Available");
    }

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    value++;
    value %= 2;


    if( k%2 == 0) { 

        switch(value){
            case 0:
                setIcon(null);
                break;
            case 1:
                setIcon(X);
                System.out.println("KX= " + k);
                break;
        }
        k++;
    }


    else {  

        switch(value){
            case 0:
                setIcon(null);
                break;
            case 1:
                setIcon(O);
                System.out.println("K0= " + k);
                break;
        }
        k++;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: ................hello?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is broken, and the main problem I see is that each XOButton has its own ActionListener, one that is completely independent of all others, and so the `value` int will always be equal to 0 whenever any button is pushed for the first time, regardless of the state of the previously pushed buttons.

I suggest that

- You don't extend JButton but rather use JButtons
- That you give all JButton's the **same** Action or ActionListener
- That this listener stores the state of the xo of the last button press
- That this listener checks to see if the currently pressed button is in a null, or X or O state, and then acts accordingly.

For an example of a working Tic Tac Toe program that uses image icons, please have a look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097448/522444) to a similar question.